# WooCommerce products location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I had a shop set up online. I started to work on something else and wanted to disable the shop so I moved all items to Trash. I didn't know thrash empties itself every 30 days so it deleted all products. How can I get them back? Even when I upload whole page from my computer again, it still remains the same? Which folder or file are products saved to? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are permanently deleted:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/trash/

> Important: Once you choose to permanently delete an item from your
>   Trash folder, there is no way to recover or restore it!

You can't restore it

> Which folder or file are products saved to?

Products are located mainly in 2 tables:

```
wp_posts table with a post_type like product or variable_product,

wp_postmeta table with a product_id by product.
```

Product categories, subcategories, and tags are located in tables:

```
wp_terms

wp_termmeta

wp_term_taxonomy

wp_term_relationships

wp_woocommerce_termmeta
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a default feature to remove the items permanently from the trash after the 30 days from the date of move item in the trash location.
You can disable this featured using the below code:

```
function wpb_remove_schedule_delete() {
    remove_action( 'wp_scheduled_delete', 'wp_scheduled_delete' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_remove_schedule_delete' );
```

or you can increase the days limit by adding the following code in the wp-config.php file.

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 30);
```